# How to enable comment folding in Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt, helios

How to enable code folding of comments for PHP scripts in Eclipse?

I have a lot of code of which the first 30 lines of every script is a GNU license... very annoying.

This seems to be somehow broken in Helios but worked by default, out of the box in Ganymede.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I correct myself the PHPDoc option folds all multi-line comments.

Note: Once enabled you have to close and reopen your file to have all the comment blocks folded.

E.g.

```
/**
 * This is a function that does something
 *
 * @param $a Some variable
 */
function doesSomething($a) {
}
```

ends up like this

```
 * This is a function that does something
function doesSomething($a) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It got me thinking and led to an experiment. Folding seems to work fine if the file contains functions as in your example. But if it's a plain old presentation-layer PHP template with a bunch of HTML and no functions, the folding of PHPDoc comments doesn't happen! The latter is what I happened to be working with.

Answer (score 1):

Under Preferences > PHP > Editor > Code Folding

Comment: According to them: *Questions about the use of PDT in user projects that are not addressed in this FAQ should be posted to the PDT newsgroup. Questions and comments regarding the implementation of PDT itself should be posted to the PDT mailing list*. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.